# Unstacking a Keras tensor as a list

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have a keras tensor of size [61,80,?] with the '?' being for batch size in custom layer. When I am trying to unstack this tensor as a list of 2D tensor of size[61,80] using tf.unstack,I am getting an error-

> ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape (61, 80, ?)

since there is no keras.backend.unstack, please suggest how to do this.

Comment: same as my problem, i tried to use tf.unstack as a alternative to using .numpy, and also getting problem with extracting subtensors. if you found the solution, it would be very kind of you to write it here please